# Accepting External Sharing Invitations Fails for Sharepoint Add-In Elements

Tags: office-365, share, sharepoint-addin, external-users

**Requirement**

I have a sharepoint provider hosted Add-In where installed in sharepoint online site collection.
There are Several Document Libraries Reside in Side the Add-In web and i want to share few documents with external Users.

**What i Tried**

I enabled external user sharing in O365 Tenant Settings

I  chose 
  `"Allow external users who accept sharing invitations and sign in as    authenticated users"` in the site collection of the Host Site is in.

Then I went Document library in the Add-In and choose the document and shared it with a outlook account.

Then the outlook account received the following email :
[image]

When the user click the email link to open the following error message was shown.

> The endpoint /sites/site Name/Add-In Name/_layouts/15/acceptinvite.aspx is not accessible in the context of a SharePoint App.

**Any one have an idea why this is happening??**

Note : I tried same steps for an item in the document library in the host web. This error didn't occur and external user was able to open the document.

Additionally tried this using CSOM programmaticaly. Same error occurred for Add-In web elements.

Thank You